# Creating a Dynamic Crossfade Animations between an Array of Drawables

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-animation

I am trying to create a slide-like interface where I would navigate between two adjacent slides with a crossfade-like animation. For instance, I would like to have a easy way to go crossfade to the next image whenever I want it to. I have been looking into the Adnroid's TransitionDrawable, but it does not seem to support the navigation I seek as you can only start the whole animation and not a specific slide. LayerDrawable, on the other hand, seem to support the navigation I want but not the animation. Any idea on how to find a clean way to do I want to do? I have implemented it already using separate animations and listeners, but it does not seem to be worth it as the number of drawables may not be specified.